# How to read special csv file by column

Tags: java, csv

I have a problem, I must to read a CSV file like:

[csv structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZAXw.png)

I want to get a list by column:

listKey1 = {value1, value11, value111, value1111}.

listKey2 = {value2, value22, value222}

....

Help me solve it!!! Please…

Comment: The whole code? Naah man, they don't acknowledge it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - parse CSV into Arrays based on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725002/java-parse-csv-into-arrays-based-on-columns)

Answer (score 1):

That's very easy to accomplish with [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial):

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
ColumnProcessor columnProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
parserSettings.setProcessor(columnProcessor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(new File("/path/to/your.csv), "UTF-8"); //all rows are submitted to the processor created above.

Map<String, List<String>> columnValues = columnProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (apache 2.0 license)